# How to add max height to my ScrollToBottom component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am currently trying to set a maxHeight to my component because when I add content (message from users) it keep expending the height of the whole page but it doesn't seem to work. I am using ScrollToBottom from the library 'react-scroll-to-bottom'.

[image]
[image]

Thank you:)

```css
    messageContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        height: '100px',
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        overflowX: 'hidden',
    },
```

```
<ScrollToBottom classes={classes.messageContainer}>
{messageList.map((data) => {
    return (
        <div
            className={classes.message}
            id={username === data.author ? "you" : "other"}
        >
            <div>
                <div className={classes.messageMeta} id={username === data.author ? "you" : "other"}>
                    <p id='time'>{data.time}</p>    
                    <p id='author'>{data.author}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.messageContent}>
                    <h4 style={{textAlign: 'right'}} id={username === data.author ? "you" : "other"}>
                         {data.message} 
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
})}
</ScrollToBottom>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use css property `max-height`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height

Comment: you try to set max height to what? where you are trying to do that?

Comment: To my ScrollToBottom tag. I have tried maxHeight but nothing is happening.. It keeps expanding above that maxHeight,

Comment: may you provide a sandbox example?

Comment: Just added some pictures. As we can see in the second picture there is no min height at all and in the first picture the maxHeight won't apply also..

Comment: overflowY was already set to scroll and maxHeight doesn't change anything ..

Comment: Yes it does normaly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the `<ScrollToBottom/>` with `div` and applied styles to the div and it works..btw, its weird when I tried setting css to `<ScrollToBottom/>` and it havent applied the css .. whatever I'm suggesting is a simple fix

```
const ScrollFunc = () => {
  const para = (
    <p>
      Laboris duis do consectetur aliquip non aliquip ad ad quis minim. Aute
      magna tempor occaecat magna fugiat culpa. Commodo id eiusmod ea pariatur
      consequat fugiat minim est anim. Ipsum amet ipsum eu nisi. Exercitation
      minim amet incididunt tempor do ut id in officia eu sit est. Dolor qui
      laboris laboris tempor sunt velit eiusmod non ipsum exercitation ut sint
      ipsum officia.
    </p>
  );

  const [paralist, setParaList] = useState(para);

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100px',
      overflowY: 'scroll',
      border: 'solid 1px blue',
    }}>
    <ScrollToBottom>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newPara = (
            <>
              {paralist}
              <br></br>
              {para}
            </>
          );
          setParaList(newPara);
        }}
      >
        Add para
      </button>
      {paralist}
    </ScrollToBottom>
    </div>
  );
};
```

demo @ [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-keaipa?file=Hello.tsx)